# What does 1 modulo p mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra

For example, from Gallian's text:

Sylow Test for Nonsimplicity

Let $n$ be a positive integer that is not prime, and let $p$ be a prime divisor of $n$. If 1 is the only divisor of $n$ that is equal to 1 modulo p, then there does not exist a simple group of order $n$.

I of course understand what some a mod b is (ex. 19 mod 10 = 9); but wouldn't 1 mod anything positive be 1 [edit: changed from 0]?

Comment: You got it the other way. Anything mod 1 is 0

Comment: Ah yes, you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To say that a number $a$ is $1$ modulo $p$ means that $p$ divides $a - 1$.  So, in particular, the numbers $1, p + 1, 2p + 1, \ldots$ are all equal to $1$ modulo $p$.

As you're studying group theory, another way to put it is that $a = b$ modulo $p$ if and only if $\pi(a) = \pi(b)$ where $\pi\colon\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/p$ is the factor homomorphism.

Comment: Great! This is what I was looking for. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

1 mod anything greater than 1 will be 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got confused between $1 mod(x)$ and $xmod(1)$.

$1mod(x) = 1$, if x>1.

$xmod(1) = 0$